# Argument passing in decorated function

Tags: python

A simple decorator that does nothing can be done like follows:

```
def decorator(func):
    return func # don't need to call!

@decorator
def print_word(word='python'):
    print (word)
```

And that will run fine:

```
>>> print_word()
python
```

But then if I wrap that in an inner function, it is called liked so:

```
def decorator(func):
    def _func(*args, **kwargs):
        print ("Args: %s | Kwargs: %s" % (args, kwargs))
        return func(*args, **kwargs) # <== Here I need to "call" it with ()
    return _func

@decorator
def print_word(word='python'):
    print (word)

>>> print_word('ok')
Args: ('ok',) | Kwargs: {}
ok
```

Why is it different in those two approaches? How does calling `_func` "bind it" to `_func(*args, **kwargs)` ?

Comment: Your decorator is essentially performing the assignment `print_word = _func`. `func` is the reference to the original definition of `print_word`. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: What is what different? And what do you mean by "bind"?

Comment: I tried to figure out where you're confused. You might also want to read through [the reference answer on decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def decorator(func):
```

Because it is a decorator, we expect it to return something that can be called.

```
    return func # don't need to call!
```

Right, because `func` is the "something that can be called" which we will return. The decorator has no effect.

> then if I wrap that in an inner function, it is called liked so

What we are doing with `_func` is creating a *new* function that will be returned by the decorator, and *defining its behaviour in terms of* the passed-in `func`. So we don't call `func` when the decorator is invoked; but we do call it inside the body of `_func`, because that's how we make `func` execute *when `_func` is executed*.

> Why is it different in those two approaches?

I don't understand the question. What is the same about them? They are both defining a decorator, okay. They do it in completely different ways.

> How does calling `_func` "bind it"

I don't understand what you mean about binding here and `_func` doesn't get called directly by name in this code. It gets called when `print_word` is called, because the decorator has replaced `print_word` with a locally created `_func`. (Every time the decorator is used, a separate function, with the same `_func` name, is made. Is that what you're stumbling on?)